# Determine the area of $\phi (A) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $ A=[0, 1] \times[0, 1] $. Let $ h $ be a continous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\phi $ be defined by 
$$\phi (x, y)=(x+h (x+y), y-h (x+y))$$
Determine the area of $\phi (A)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Note that $\mu(A\cap l)=\mu(\phi(A)\cap l)$ for all lines $l$ of the form $x+y=\text{const}$.